# How to manage AWS EC2 jobs with a due date while minimising cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, gpgpu, aws-batch

I'm building a backend service for an image-processing app. User-created images are uploaded in groups of 20-40 images to Firebase Cloud Storage, and need to be processed by GPU-accelerated hardware, for which I plan to use Amazon EC2, before going back to storage to be downloaded by the user application.

Each group of images has a "due date" which is generated server-side, and may be anywhere from 8 hours to 72 hours from submission. This metadata will be stored in Cloud Firestore where the groups will be indexed by their due date for easy queuing. On a G4ad or G4dn EC2 instance, I estimate that one group of images should take less than one minute to process.

I want to minimise the total server cost by taking advantage of EC2 spot prices; however, it is fairly critical that jobs are finished before their "due date" (e.g. when 1 hour remains on the next due job, I should forgo the spot prices and just pay the on-demand prices). I don't anticipate enough volume initially to justify a dedicated instance or commit to higher usage plans.

*How could I architect a solution that minimises cost while respecting the due date of jobs?*

### What I've already considered

#### 1. AWS Batch

AWS Batch seems to be used commonly for queuing jobs. I could enqueue jobs specifying the IDs of the images to be processed, and the job would then fetch these images when running.

However, AWS Batch only seems to support an approximate FIFO ordering of jobs (while I want them to be ordered by their due date). I also don't see a mechanism to switch between spot/on-demand instances based on the time in the queue.

#### 2. Manual management

I could allocate a Spot instance and an On-Demand instance, and switch between the two depending on the due date of the next job. I'd probably set up a cloud function on AWS Lambda or google cloud to poll (at regular intervals e.g. 5 minutes) the due date of the next due job in Firestore:

- If there is no job, do nothing;
- If there is a job due in the next hour, and the Spot instance is not running, start the On-Demand instance. This instance will process the next due jobs (from Firestore) until the queue is empty or at least an hour ahead;
- Otherwise (there is a job due in more than an hour), attempt to start the Spot instance. If there is capacity available, the instance will run continuously but terminate itself if it finishes the entire queue.

I'm unsure if this is a good approach so I am open to any feedback or alternatives.

Comment: How long does it take to process a single image?

Comment: I haven't tested on this hardware yet; my mid-end graphics card can do them in perhaps 8-10 seconds. It varies with the content of the image.

Comment: They are always batched into predefined group sizes, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using only spot instances is a good choice for you. Yes, spot instances are prefect for batch image processing on condition that you can tolerate their unpredictable nature. They can be started/terminated at any time.

Since your batch jobs are **time critical**, I think it would be better to have on-demand instances (can save lots with [reserved instances](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-optimization/reserved-instances/)) which you can always relay on and don't worry about them being terminated just before your due dates.

As a compromise you could use [spot fleets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html). The spot fleet allow you to launch a mixture of on-demand and spot-instances. In your case on-demand portion in the fleet should be large enough to handle **entire workload** in case there are no spot capacity. If there is spot capacity, then that's good, your batch processing will finish earlier and you save money. In the worst case, ever image is processed by the on-demand instances by the due day.

SQS FIFO queues do **preserver order** of messages, so you don't have to worry about images being processed in different order then submitted to the queue. But then FIFO queues pose some issue with parallel processing as you always have to keep order of messages. You would have to use different **message groups** in FIFO SQS to be able to process messages in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Running time per node type is variable/controllable which makes the following:

```
Cost1 = ( node1 price per hour ) x (  running time1 )
Cost2 = ( node2 price per hour ) x ( running time2 )
...
Costn = (node n...) x ( running time n)
Total cost = sum of cost 1 + .... + cost n
Fitness = 1.0/  (total cost  * normalized due date breach ratio)
```

A solvable problem by genetic algorithm if you can use the total time (due date) constraint by predicting image processing performance of gpus.

Since you already have gpus at hand, it would take milliseconds, if not seconds, to solve it.

Even if you mis-predict static gpu performances, it would converge to solution if you solve it repeatedly during whole computation time and adjust the server allocation dynamically. (You can measure current performance of each node by measuring work given to them and their response time and adjust the work distribution accordingly for next iteration of genetic algorithm)

---

Another way could be:

- start 1 server
- if due time is 50% approached and tasks are less than 50% complete
- - then start 2 more servers
- if due time is 75% approached and tasks are less than 75% complete
- - then start 4 more servers
- if due time is 87% apprached and tasks are less than 87% complete
- - then start 8 more servers
- if 94% .... then 16 servers
- if 97% ... then 32 servers

This may not be as efficient as solving the minimization problem.